# Non- zero polynomial can be written as product of polynomials of degree at most two

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Prove that every non-zero polynomial $\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ can be written as product of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree at most two.

Is there elementary proof, at high school level ?

Please, suggest me on how to prove or lead me to the link.Thank you.

(Fundamental theorem of Algebra is quite hard for me.)

Comment: Every non- zero polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots which are complex conjugate like $z-z_0$ and $z-\bar{z_0}$ and $(z-z_0)(z-\bar{z_0})$ is a polynomial with of degree at most two and with real coefficients.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is indeed quite hard, but I don't see any way to prove this without it.  After all, without knowing that theorem there might be an irreducible quartic or higher degree polynomial.

Comment: This *is* the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove the statement by [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_induction). Of course, the statement is trivial if the degree of the polynomial is $1$ or $2$. Suppose that you have a polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n>2$ and assume that every non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ whose degree is smaller than $n$ can be written as a product of polynomials with degree $1$ or $2$.

Let $x_0$ be a root of $P(x)$; the Fundamental theorem of Algebra assures that such a root existes. Let us consider two possibilites: $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $x_0\notin\mathbb R$.

- Since $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $x_0$ is a root of $P(x)$, $P(x)$ can be written as $Q(x)(x-x_0)$, with $Q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Since the degree of $Q(x)$ is $n-1$, $Q(x)$ can be written as product of polynomials whose degree is $1$ or $2$ and therefore $P(x)$ has the same property.
- It happens that $\overline{x_0}$ is a root of $P(x)$ too, because, since the coefficients of $P(x)$ are real, $\overline{P\bigl(\overline{x_0}\bigr)}=P(x_0)=0$ and therefore $P\bigl(\overline{x_0}\bigr)=0$. Since $x_0$ and $\overline{x_0}$ are distinct roots of $P(x)$, $P(x)$ can be written as $Q(x)(x-x_0)\bigl(x-\overline{x_0}\bigr)$. Furthermore,$$(x-x_0)\bigl(x-\overline{x_0}\bigr)=x^2-2\operatorname{Re}(x_0)x+|x_0|^2\in\mathbb{R}[x]$$and this implies that $Q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Since the degree of $Q(x)$ is $n-2$, $Q(x)$ can be written as product of polynomials whose degree is $1$ or $2$ and therefore $P(x)$ has the same property.

Comment: I got it :) Thank you for your help, Jose Carlos Santos.

Answer (score 4):

We need to assume that if $n$ is a degree of our polynomial $f$ then $f$ has $n$ roots from $\mathbb C$.

Try to prove the following statements.

- > If $z\in\mathbb C$ is a root of our polynomial then $\bar{z}$ is a root of $f$.
- > If previous  $z=a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are reals, then $f$ divided by $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2$.
- > If $c\in\mathbb R$ is a root of $f$ thus, $f$ divided by $x-c$

  and by induction we are done!

Comment: Thank you, Micheal Rozenberg.

Comment: @carat You are welcome!